# Springboot 3.0.0-M2 AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to create a backend using spring boot.
When I executed the application, this exception was thrown:

> Field authenticationManager in projekt.controller.AuthController
> required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'
> that could not be found.

I quickly found a solution on the internet, which includes adding a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in which I would add this method:

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

But as I had to see, this is [deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter).

My question is how would I do the same thing without using something deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

In your configuration class you can add this:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) 
         throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```